# Abstract factory implementation within C# application

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I'd like to implement [abstract factory design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern). I add this snippet :

```
  public class Class1
{

   static Ete _ete;
   static Hiver _hiver;


    public static void Main(Clothes cl)
    {
        _ete = cl.CreateEteClothes();
        _hiver = cl.CreateHiverClothes();
        Console.WriteLine(_ete.GetMarque());
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.WriteLine(_hiver.GetMarque());
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}


public abstract class Clothes
{
    public abstract Ete CreateEteClothes();
    public abstract Hiver CreateHiverClothes();

}


public abstract class ItalianFactory: Clothes
{
    public override Ete CreateEteClothes()
    {
        return new TShirtJuve();
    }

    public override Hiver CreateHiverClothes()
    {
        return new PullJuve();
    }
}
public abstract class FrenchFactory : Clothes
{
    public override Ete CreateEteClothes()
    {
        return new TShirtPsg();
    }

    public override Hiver CreateHiverClothes()
    {
        return new PullPsg();
    }

}

public abstract class TunisianFactory : Clothes
{
    public override Ete CreateEteClothes()
    {
        return new TShirtCa();
    }

    public override Hiver CreateHiverClothes()
    {
        return new PullCa();
    }

}

public abstract class Ete
{ 
public abstract string GetMarque();
}

public abstract class Hiver
{
    public abstract string GetMarque();
}

public class TShirtJuve: Ete
{

    public override string GetMarque()
    {
        return "Juventus T shirt";
    }
}

public class TShirtPsg : Ete
{

    public override string GetMarque()
    {
        return "PSG T shirt";
    }
}

public class TShirtCa : Ete
{

    public override string GetMarque()
    {
        return "club africain T shirt";
    }
}


public class PullJuve : Hiver
{

    public override string GetMarque()
    {
        return "Juventus Pull";
    }
}

public class PullPsg : Hiver
{

    public override string GetMarque()
    {
        return "PSg Pull";
    }
}
public class PullCa : Hiver
{

    public override string GetMarque()
    {
        return "Club africain Pull";
    }
}
```

I'd like to test this implementation, but I get an exception indicates that the signature of main method is not acceptable.

So How can I fix my code to test this design pattern implementation?

Comment: Test using a unit test, not by adding things to a Main method

Comment: I agree with Erno de weerd...what is cl in cl.CreateEteClothes(); shouldnt you create a new instance of the type? Like _ete = new TShirtJuve();
_hiver = new PullJuve();

Comment: This should be re-titled to "What is wrong with my main method" as it has nothing to do with how to implement the Abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `public static void Main(Clothes cl)`

This should be `static void Main(string[] args)` as this is the entry point for the application and there can be only one entry point. See the [.NET documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) for more info.

A method's signature usually consists of the methods name, return type, and parameters. Your application is expecting the correct signature for the Main method, hence it's giving you this exception.